# Write data with Python into existing excel file keeping it intact as much as possible

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

We have a rather complicated Excel based VBA Tool that shall be replaced by a proper Database and Python based application step by step.

There will be time of the transition between were the not yet completely ready Python tool and the already existing VBA solution will coexist.

To allow interoperability the Python tool must be able to export the database values into the Excel VBA Tool keeping it intact. Meaning that not only all VBA codes have to work as expected but also Shapes, Special Formats etc, Checkboxes etc. have to work after the export.

Currently a simple:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(r'Tool.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
# Write some data i.e. (not required to destroy the file)
wb["SomeSheet!SomeCell"] = "SomeValue"
wb.save(r"Tool_filled.xlsm")
```

will destroy the file, i.e. shapes won't work, checkboxes neither. (The resulting file is only 5 MB from originally 8 MB, showing that something went quite wrong).

Is there a way to only modify only the data of an ExcelSheet keeping **everything** else intact/untouched?

As far I know an Excel Sheet are only zipped `.xml` files. So it should be possible to edit only the related sheets? Correct?
Is there a more comfortable way as writing everything from scratch to **only** modify the data of an existing Excel file?

Note: The solution has to work in Linux, so simple remote Excel calls are not an option.

Comment: This is currently not possible though would, in theory, be possible with openpyxl.

Comment: @CharlieClark Can you elaborate on 'why' this is not possible? I was thinking about overwriting openpyxl's ExcelWriter, the related WorbookWriter and WorksheetWriter in a way that the original zip file is only modified. To be specific, that only the `xml` file of the sheet for which data was changed is touched. And there only the dimensions and cells part.
Would this work?

Comment: It's not possible because support for the relevant parts has not been implemented. You might get away with making minor changes to the package yourself but the "plumbing" of these files is complicated and easily broken.

Comment: @CharlieClark, what do you think how likely is it to succeed (the plumbing)? What are possible Pitfalls? Auto Format? References?

Comment: Any discussion should be continued per e-mail but the use of "pointers" in the packaging is usually the source of much mirth.